# Different behaviour between "include_once" and directly echoing out html code?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm afraid the question is related to my (still) limited PHP and JS competence.
During some exercises (for something that shall become eventually a WordPress plugin) I came across the following behavior that I can not explain!

To draw a menu I hooked a method called *display_menu()* to the *wp_nav_menu_items* filter.
Here is the method:

```
 public function display_menu( $items, $args ) {
    include_once <path>/partials-off-canvas.php';
    }
```

In *partials-off-canvas.php* we only have

```
<div class="menu">
    <p>Menue Entry 1</p>
    <p>Menue Entry 2</p>
    <p>Menue Entry 3</p>
</div>
<div class="menu_toggle_icon">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

With some JS (and CSS) it works as a menue toggle button that opens a menu.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

        $(function() {
            const toggle_icon = document.querySelector('.menu_toggle_icon');
            const menu    = document.querySelector('.menu');
            
            /*
             * Toggles on and off the 'active' class on the menu
             * and the toggle button.
             */
            toggle_icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
              toggle_icon.classList.toggle('active');
              menu.classList.toggle('active');
            })
        });
    
    })( jQuery );
```

Here is how I added the JS script.
I used a plugin boilerplate: https://wppb.me/.
There I hooked a function to *wp_enqueue_scripts*.
This function calls

```
wp_enqueue_script($this->plugin_name,
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/fancymenu-public.js',
    array('jquery'),
    $this->version,
    false);
```

So far so good.
For training reasons I changed the *display_menu()* method a bit:

```
public function display_menu( $items, $args ) {
    echo '
    <div class="menu">
        <p>Menue Entry 1</p>
        <p>Menue Entry 2</p>
        <p>Menue Entry 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_toggle_icon">
    <span></span>
    </div>';
    }
```

Actually I expected the exact same result as before.
But that's not exactly the case.
Though the visual result in the front-end is the same (I can see the menu toggle icon) it seems no longer be tied to the JS 'click' event.
If I click on the icon nothing happens.

Now I'm curious what I haven't understand and what are the differences between both versions of `display_menu()`?

Comment: There’s absolutely no difference between the two that would affect JavaScript. PHP doesn’t know anything about HTML. As far as it’s concerned it’s just printing text. The browser interpreters the HTML and if the text is the same the DOM will be the same. Your question leaves out how you’re loading the JavaScript though, can you include that information?

Comment: If you're adding a filter on `wp_nav_menu_items` it expects you to return data. Echoing or producing HTML at the point a filter runs is incorrect usage of a filter. You can either append/prepend the incoming `$items` html or replace it, but in either case your data should be returned.

Comment: @JacobPeattie: I added the information to my question. Let me know if you need more information.
Anyhow: good to know that I was not completely wrong in expecting no difference between both versions. :-)

Comment: @t31os_: I guess this is not directly related to my question?
Still very good advice, since it answers probably some questions, I still have in mind.
I was kind of aware of it, but still manged to do it wrong. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @JacobPeattie: Hi Jacob, I added the information you requested. Do you have any suggestion on the cause of the behavior I observed?
Thanks Christian

Comment: @cortlieb I don't see how you loaded the JS?

Comment: @JacobPeattie: Oh, I'm sorry, you're completely right, I missed the information about loading the JS script. I added it a while ago, but obviously I missed to save it correctly. So I was under the impression that the requested information is already available. But now it should be there.